# Catalogo digital

Tags: php, mysql

`

```
                            <?php 




                            
                            $result_estoque = "SELECT estoque FROM produto";
                            $resultado_estoque = mysqli_query($conn, $result_estoque);
                            $result_estoque >= 1;
                            if($result_estoque >= 0)
                            echo "<font color=\"#008000\">Disponível</font></b>";
                            elseif($result_estoque <= 0)
                            echo "<font color=\"#FF0000\">Indisponível</font></b>"; 







                    ?></h3>`
```

Coloquei acima o meu if.
Estou montando um catalogo digital que puxa as informações dos produtos do meu banco de dados,
eu gostaria de saber como faço para em vez de mostrar a quantidade de produtos que tem no estoque, ele mostrar o nome Disponível quando tiver produtos no estoque e indisponível quando o estoque estiver zerado. gostaria de saber como fazer esse if?

[[image: imagem do catalogo]
<sup>clique na imagem para visualiza-la em seu tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz6KD.jpg)

```
<div class="row">
            <?php while($rows_produtos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produtos)){ ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="imagens/produto.jpg" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption text-center">
                            <a href="detalhes.php?id_curso=<?php echo $rows_produtos['id']; ?>"><h3>Produto <br><?php echo $rows_produtos['nome']; ?></h3><h3>Descrição <br><?php echo $rows_produtos['descricao']; ?></h3><h3>R$ <?php echo $rows_produtos['valor_venda']; ?></h3><h3>Código: <?php echo $rows_produtos['codigo']; ?></h3><h3>Estoque: <?php echo $rows_produtos['estoque']; ?></h3></a>

                        

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Estrutura da tabela produtos]

Comment: tentei da seguinte forma $estoque = 1;
if($estoque == 1)
    echo "Disponível";
elseif($estoque == 0)
    echo "Indisponível";

Comment: porém sem sucesso

Comment: Você pode editar a pergunta para incluir as o formações que comentou.

Comment: Qual a consulta realizada para gerar os valores da variável `$rows_produtos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produtos)` ?

Comment: include_once("conexao.php");
$result_produtos = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
$resultado_produtos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produtos);

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer esse `if` tanto na linguagem de programação como na linguagem de consulta SQL.

**No SQL:**

```
Select @estoque := 1 as Estoque, 
       IF(@estoque>0, "Disponível", "Indisponível") as Disponibilidade;
```

**Resultado:**

| Estoque | Disponibilidade |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Disponível |

**Observação:**

Consulta SQL acima apenas para exemplificar. O `@estoque` do trecho `IF(@estoque>0, "Disponível", "Indisponível")` deve ser substituído pelo campo da sua tabela.

Leia mais sobre a [função **IF** no MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if)

Comment: no meu banco de dados eu tenho a tabela Produtos e dentro da tabela produtos eu tenho a tabela Estoque, que recebe os valores definidos no cadastro dos produtos. quando o valor for 0 eu quero que ele mostre para o cliente a informação de indisponível e quando o valor for maior que 0 ele informe para o cliente que o produto está disponível, fiz vários testes e ainda não consegui aplicar o IF, lembrando que sou iniciante! agradeço pela atenção!

Comment: Como está a sua consulta SQL inicial? Tentou aplicar o IF que mencionei? Qual a estrutura da sua tabela? Edite a pergunta é informe as Estruturas das tabelas.

Comment: fiz mas ainda não deu certo.